# Sinon stub an axios post, the return value is a undefined and can't be resolved

Tags: javascript, axios, sinon

function to be tested

```
export const get_drawing_data = (url, request_obj) => {
  axios
    .post(url, JSON.stringify(request_obj), {
      headers: {
        // Overwrite Axios's automatically set Content-Type
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Sinon stub is used to intercept the Axios post call. It simulates the axios.post return value which is a Promise. The resolve of the Promise takes the API response data as a value. So the following line use sinon.stub resolves function created a promise as axios `post` function return value.

```
describe("test axios get_drawing_data", () => {
  it("test input and output", () => {
    const requestData = {a: "hello world"};

    const responseData = "hellow world";
    sinon.stub(axios, "post").resolves(responseData);

    const response = get_drawing_data("http://127.0.0.1/xxx", requestData);
    expect(response).toEqual(["hello world"]);
  });
});
```

The expectation is response.data should be equal to the constructed value in Promise. But actually it's a undefined.

> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: ["hello world"]
> Received: undefined
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here...

1. Your `get_drawing_data` function doesn't return anything
2. The Axios defaults are already perfect for posting JSON without custom headers or payload transformation
3. Don't catch promise rejections and transform the promise into a resolved one, especially by resolving with an `undefined` value. Your consumers will not handle that response correctly.
4. You'd probably be more interested in the Axios response `data` than the [entire response](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)
5. You should await the result of calling `get_drawing_data()`
6. Not sure why you'd expect an array when you've already told it what to return

With that in mind, try the following

```js
export const get_drawing_data = async (url, request_obj) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(url, request_obj);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("get_drawing_data", err.toJSON());
    throw err; // keep the promise chain rejected
  }
};
```

or if you don't like `async / await`...

```js
// note the arrow function has no `{...}`, ie an implicit return
export const get_drawing_data = (url, request_obj) =>
  axios
    .post(url, request_obj)
    .then(({ data }) => data)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("get_drawing_data", err.toJSON());
      return Promise.reject(err); // keep the promise chain rejected
    });
```

and in your test

```js
describe("test axios get_drawing_data", () => {
  it("test input and output", async () => { // async function here
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1/xxx";
    const requestData = { a: "hello world" };

    const responseData = "hellow world";
    // resolve with something closer to the Axios response schema
    sinon.stub(axios, "post").resolves({ data: responseData });

    // await the result
    const response = await get_drawing_data(url, requestData);

    // verify the stub was called as expected
    sinon.assert.calledWith(axios.post, url, requestData);

    // compare the response with what you actually set up
    expect(response).toEqual(responseData);
  });
});
```

Comment: Good catch and very good advice. Not a must but just out of curiosity if I’d like not use await in get_drawing_data, still prefer using .then, do I have to return a Promise in get_drawing_data function? No other choice? Does it mean get_drawing_data function can’t be a consumer? @Phil

Comment: @cdhit I've updated my answer to include a promise method (`.then()` / `.catch()`) version

Comment: This answer helps me a lot.

Though I had some experience on programming. I am just a few days of experience on top of Axios and Sinon. 

The Javascript concept Promise in single thread Browser environment is not easy for the newbies. I am pretty sure my mistakes (quite a lot of them here as shown) and your answer will be very helpful. @Phil.

Comment: @cdhit you're welcome. Getting your head around async programming is always a bit of a trial.